# Why can't I connect to my WCHLink-E on Windows?

Tags: microcontroller, programmer

I bought a WCHLink-E to flash a CH32V003 and none of the tools (minichlink, WCH-LinkUtility, etc) could connect to it! (I'm on Windows) Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I needed to apparently update the device, which you can do by making a hole in the case of the device and holding down the S button with a paperclip when you plug it in. Then the WCH-LinkUtility will recognize the device and ask you to update the firmware. After that everything seems to work as expected!

EDIT: In addition the blue light turned off, which apparently means that it's now in RISC-V mode as opposed to ARM mode, which you need anyways. I don't think it's related with not being able to connect to the WCHLink-E though.
[image]